# Validation of a CQ5 dialog through regex

Tags: regex, validation, dialog, aem

I have a widget for my dialog, which I would like to validate using a Regex.

Here are its properties:

```
<widget
    regex="/^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$/"
    regexText="Please enter a valid email address"
    xtype="textfield"
    fieldLabel="Email"
    name="./email"
    allowBlank="false"/>
```

Whenever I input a valid email address, it always returns false. I have admittedly zero prior knowledge on working with regex.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: which email id returned false?an example..

Comment: Try this and check if it works? /^[A-za-z0-9]+[\\._]*[A-za-z0-9]*@[A-za-z.-]+[\\.]+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/
I think there is some prob with your regex only.

Comment: @NaveedS tried a simple email id:- `john.doe@example.com`

Comment: @Rakhi your regex worked for me. If you would list it out as an answer, I would accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex, this one works for me.

```
/^[A-za-z0-9]+[\\._]*[A-za-z0-9]*@[A-za-z.-]+[\\.]+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

For people with similar issues who are searching this on google:

Open CRXDE and edit the dialog by double-clicking on the dialog icon. It will open a special dialog editor. Select the text field you want to edit and enter the regex in the UI. Enter only a Javascript-valid regex. Find and use a Regex tester on google if you need to, to ensure it is valid. Save the dialog then look at the JCR (remember to refresh CRXDE as it caches old content) or export using package manager.

Some common issues:

Must start and end with "/".

```
/foobar/
```

All XML characters need to be escaped. I don't know why, it seems very odd to me.

```
/Surf&amp;Turf/
/&lt;html>/
```

Slashes must be escaped with backslash. Backslash must be escaped with backslash. (Just use character classes, it's cleaner anyway).

```
/http:\\/\\/www\\.google\\.com/
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following should work for you `regex:- /^[a-zA-Z][\\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$/`

Comment: thanks for your response. while this works for something like `john.doe@gmail.com` it fails if my email id includes a company domain name. for example `john.doe@company.com`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that runs in adobe cq5, try it out

```
/^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/
```